# jQuery and multiple selection options

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to send to values with one <select> option in HTML - here is my <select>, I am not even sure if I have the value set up right to send to jQuery.

```
<select id="needapproval" name="needapproval">
  <option value="">* * * Select * * *</option>
  <cfloop query="GetApprover">
    <option VALUE="{'theID': '#GetApprover.rar_ID#',
      'roomname': '#GetApprover.theroom#'}">Request Number - #GetApprover.rar_ID#
      - Room/Gate Name -#GetApprover.theroom#</option>
  </cfloop>
</select>
```

OK, once I select the value above I do an `onchange` event in jQuery. Values sent:

```
{'theID': '29', 'roomname': 'red room'}
```

How do I grab the two values and set them to vars - below is my jQuery, I know it is wrong:

```
var theID = $("#needapproval.theID").val();
var roomname = $("#needapproval.roomname").val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those values with some modification to your markup like below,

```
<select id="needapproval" name="needapproval">
<option value="">* * * Select * * *</option>
<cfloop query="GetApprover">
<option VALUE='{"theID":"#GetApprover.rar_ID#","roomname":"#GetApprover.theroom#"}'>Request Number - #GetApprover.rar_ID# - Room/Gate Name -#GetApprover.theroom#</option>
</cfloop>
</select>
```

Note the single quotes and double quotes in the VALUE attr.

And then you can do `JSON.parse()` on the value to get the `theID` and `roomname`. See below,

```
$(function () {
    $('#needapproval').change(function () {
        var selectedVal = $(this).val();        
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(selectedVal);
        alert(jsonObj.theID + " " + jsonObj.roomname);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/W2M6G/)